# How to use setInterval with a pause between loops?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval

In my react component, once the component loads, I am trying to repeat a task every 100ms and after 3 repetitions pause for 1 second. Then repeat this pattern indefinitely.

I want to achieve this output:

```
1 // pause 100ms
2 // pause 100ms
3 // pause 100ms
// pause 1second
... repeat
```

I tried something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  let i = 0

  function increment() {
    if (i === 3) {
      // i = 0
      // restart timer?
      // return?
    }
    i++
    console.log(i)
  }

  const incrementTimer = setInterval(increment, 100)

  setInterval(() => {
    clearInterval(incrementTimer)
  }, 1000)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `recursive` function within `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function start(i = 1) {
    const reset = i > 3;
    const time = reset ? 1000 : 100;

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      task(i, time); // -> run your task
      start(reset ? 1 : i + 1); recursive call to schedule next task
      clearTimeout(timeout); // -> clear 
    }, time);
  }

  start();
}, []);

function task(i, time) {
  console.log('task is running: ', i, time);
}
```

**Working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jenzmw?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Beautifully done!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via setTimeout.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let i = 0
  let incrementTimer
  function increment() {
    if (i === 3) {
      // i = 0
      // restart timer?
      // return?
    }
    i++
    console.log(i)
     incrementTimer = setTimeout(increment, 100)
  }

  increment()

  setInterval(() => {
    clearInterval(incrementTimer)
  }, 1000)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a state to determine at which level the component is.

```
const [levelIndex, setLevelIndex] = useState(0);
```

Then create an array for execution time at each level (*This is For the case that you are looking for, it can be changed depending on what time spans are needed or which pattern a user wants*).

```
const intevalExecutionTime = [100,100,100,1000];
```

Next create a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
  //**write the task that you want to be done.**
    if(levelIndex === 3){
      setLevelIndex(0);
      console.log(`one second paused`);
    }
    else{
      setLevelIndex(levelIndex+1);
      console.log('task is done.');
    }
    clearInterval(timer);
  }, intevalExecutionTime[levelIndex])
}, [levelIndex]);
```

This hook callback will set an interval based on the **interval execution time level**. Every time the `setInterval` callback is triggered the older interval object will be removed and it changes the `levelIndex` and the `useEffect` callback will be called once again.